# Is there a translation of "A fool and his money are soon parted"

Tags: перевод, idioms

I am wondering if there is a Russian equivalent of the English idiom `"A fool and his money are soon parted"`.

Comment: "Дурак платит дважды"? It's not exactly same, but I guess it's close...

Comment: 1. Без ума торговать – только деньги терять (Trading out of mind is only losing money). 2. На деньги ума не купишь. (One can't buy brains for money). 3. У дурака в горсти дыра. (A fool has a hole in his handful).

Comment: @Alissa "**Скупой** платит дважды", not "дурак".

Comment: Damn. Sorry. It mixed up in my head, as I've heard a longer version: "Скупой платит дважды, а дурак трижды"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In numerous Russian books this English idiom (its sense: "*Дурак легко расстаётся с деньгами*")  is compared with the Russian proverb: "**У дурака в горсти дыра**". An example of such a book: *Пословицы и поговорки - 
английские, немецкие, французские с русским переводом (Энтраст Трейдинг, Москва 2015).*

The page:
https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=A7nYCQAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA11&img=1&zoom=3&ots=mRzKWAIIUY&sig=ACfU3U28TmxXWPOptmFAuwRawvK62wHw0g&w=1280

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of proverbs meaning roughly 'it is not worth being a fool'. I'd vote for the last one as the closest Russian equivalent of the English idiom you have mentioned - though the first one might match some meaning of the phrase as well.

***Дурак деньги напоказ носит.***

***Дураки о добыче спорят, а умные разделили ее.***

***Дурень и дом сожжет, так огню рад.***

***Дурак дом построил, а умница купил.***

***Дурак торгует, когда базар кончится.***

***Дураки да нищие не родом ведутся, а кому Б-г даст.*** (though here 'дурак' means rather 'mad' than 'a fool'.

***Дураку все копейка.***

Last, but not least, you can also use the not-so-delicate and less classical, but nontheless explicit ***Недолго музыка играла*** (sometimes followed by ***недолго фраер танцевал***). This phrase can be used in a broader conext.